# Add '<script>' in react component

Tags: reactjs

I wants to add following script tag in react component

```
<script>
window.fcSettings = {
token: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
host: "https://wchat.freshchat.com",
siteId: "SITE_ID"               // OPTIONAL: id unique to your site
};
</script>
```

in my react component i did like following

```
componentDidMount() {
var fc_JS=document.createElement('script');
fc_JS.type='text/javascript';
(document.body?document.body:document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]).appendChild(fc_JS);window.token='xxxxxxx';window.host='host_name';
window.siteId: "SITE_ID";
}
```

but not working

Also following for following  code in html template file is  working

```
<div id='freshteam-widget'></div>
-<script src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/files.freshteam.com/attachments/10003920/original/0212_widget.js?15526251'></script>
```

but in this way in react

```
componentDidMount() {
var fc_JS=document.createElement('script');
fc_JS.type='text/javascript';    fc_JS.src='url';
        console.log(fc_JS)
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(fc_JS);
}

 render() {
  return (
    <div id='freshteam-widget'></div>
)
}
```

not working

kindly help

Comment: is there a reason you aren't adding the script html tags to the initial render?

Comment: @JonathanHolland react render doesn't allow script tag

Comment: What's the problem with putting the script tag in your root HTML file?

Comment: @AndrewLi for common layout its fine, but for only for specific react component how can i use..

Comment: @Anish What do you mean...? Why would you need it 'for only a specific react component'? Just include it in the root HTML file that React renders to...

Comment: You could do the same thing via dangerouslySetInnerHTML - but there is a reason it is named this :) - can you set these settings in react code instead of needing this script at all?

@AndrewLi I think it is because they might pass in the site ID for that token?

Comment: You want to try out https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-load-script, but i think it is better you can place it in root html

Answer (score -1):

You may want to use [react-helmet](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet).

```
import Helmet from "react-helmet";

//inside the render method
render() {
  return(
    <div>
      <Helmet
        script={[
          { innerHTML: `
           window.fcSettings = { token: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",host: "https://wchat.freshchat.com", siteId: "SITE_ID"};
          `}
        ]}
      />
      {/*the rest of your code here*/}
    </div>
  );
}
```